# how to make "if condition" multiple of two

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

i want to make `if` condition. in that condition, if the condition is score = multiple of two. how to make the code?

```
if(score >= 2){         
            //removeChild(Batumc);
            //removeChild(Batumc1);

            //model soal
            Soal_mc.angka1.text = mtk1.toString();
            Soal_mc.op.text = "+";
            Soal_mc.angka2.text = mtk2.toString();

            //soal muncul
            TweenLite.to(Soal_mc, 1, {x:350 ,y:180, alpha:1, ease:Expo.easeOut});
            }
```

but i want this code

```
if(score >= 2)
```

become to

```
if(score multiple of 2){}
```

Comment: if((score % 2) == 0) {} (Look up "modulo operator" for an explanation, or I can write a more detailed answer if you like)

Comment: sure, if you approve. please explain in simple explanation :)

Comment: Modulo is simply a division operation but instead of returning the quotient it returns the remainder. Since an even number divided by 2 has no remainder, you can ensure a number is a multiple of two if you use `score % 2 == 0`, as any even number will return 0 and any odd will return 1.

Comment: thank's @ugotopia123

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(score >=2) {
    if((score % 2) == 0) {
        //your code goes here
    }
}
```

The `score % 2` returns the remainder of the division, and if this return is equals to `0`, it means is multiple.

Comment: I think so, but if i don't  use ````if(score >= 2)````, can i? it is effective just to use ````if((score % 2) == 0)````, isn't it?

Comment: Yes! I just add this condition because I thought that you want to have a score superior ou equals to 2